# How to remove extra space at the bottom introduced by includestandalone

Tags: standalone, includegraphics, vertical-spacing

I am trying to move a table to a standalone file (s.tex) in my LaTeX document (a.tex). However, I realize that when I use `\includestandalone{s}`, LaTeX includes an extra vertical space after the table (see screenshot below). The white space above the table also decreases. If I use `\input{s}`, everything is fine.

[image: demo picture]

How can I still use `\includestandalone` but remove the extra whitespace, so my LaTeX document does not change?

To reproduce:

a.tex:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}

WWW

\includestandalone{s}

WWW

\input{s}

WWW

\begin{tabular}{ | l | }\hline
a \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

WWW

\end{document}
```

s.tex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | }\hline
a \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```